# jQuery Get the value of two textfields inside a <p> or <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the values of two text fields that are inside a `<p> </p>` so I can submit them via ajax. I'm stuck with how to get the values efficiently. There are several `<p></p>` on the page like this and I only need to get the values of the `<p></p>` container which I click `'Approve'` or `'Delete'`.
My method is pretty crude. Can you suggest something more elegant and efficient?

```
<body>

<p class="rawData">
<span>
<input class="minWeight" type="text" placeholder="Minimum Weight">
<input class="maxWeight" type="text" placeholder="Maximum Weight">
</span>
<span class="actions">
<i class="icon-accept blue approve"></i>
<i class="icon-reject blue delete"></i>
</span>
</p>

<p class="rawData">
<span>
<input class="minWeight" type="text" placeholder="Minimum Weight">
<input class="maxWeight" type="text" placeholder="Maximum Weight">
</span>
<span class="actions">
<i class="icon-accept blue approve"></i>
<i class="icon-reject blue delete"></i>
</span>
</p>

</body>

$('.approve,.delete').live('click', function() {

    var self = $(this);
    console.log(self.parent().parent()//find etc);

});
```

Comment: Is there a reason they don't have unique IDs? Do they get created dynamically without a set quantity?

Comment: Yes. They get created dynamically. just the way you see them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `closest` to find the first parent instance of `rawData`, then filter from there:

```
$('.approve,.delete').on('click', function() {
    var $raw = $(this).closest(".rawData");
    console.log($raw.find("minWeight").val());
    console.log($raw.find("minWeight").val());
});
```

Comment: closest("p") is more efficient here

Comment: @jmenezes, Notice the use of 'on' instead of 'live'. This is since 1.7. Keep this in mind as well. http://api.jquery.com/on/